# VS 2017 builds code redundantly when switching from msbuild console build over to IDE (the first time)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

VS 2017 sets `LastActiveSolutionConfig` for a web application on its project load, thus triggering subsequent build of that project, because:

- The property is set in the respective `.csproj.user` file, which is created, if needed.
- The `.csproj.user` file is part of project dependencies

So by creating it, VS causes the project to be built the next time.

Imagine building it all on the command line with msbuild after cleaning up the workspace, then switching back to VS and hitting the build button. And it is building again!

1. So, there are these stupid auto generated CS files related to workflows, that are generated only by VS, not msbuild (`TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs` and friends) - our msbuild generates them on purpose to satisfy VS. Check.
2. Next we ensure all the Copy to Output Directory files use `PreserveNewest` - check.

I already forgot what else we had to do to make sure VS does not rebuild code redundantly when switching from msbuild to IDE. Now this one, which is new.

How can I prevent VS 2017 from adding this property? Is it absolutely necessary to have it?

In the mean-time, I will modify the `.csproj` files by adding it and see if it helps. Nobody builds `Release` locally at our place and it is always `AnyCPU` platform, so I do not care about other configurations, except `Debug|AnyCPU`.

Comment: It seems you've found the alternative workaround(generating the file during build), you could consider adding it as answer to share the useful info. And if you do need the function that msbuild or VS have settings to manage this behavior, I suggest you can feel free to post your request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to generate the .csproj.user files if needed with the expected property. Which is incredibly annoying that one has to do it. Here is the build code that can go into your `Directory.Build.Targets`:

```xml
  <Target Name="EnsureCSProjUserForWebApplications" 
          Condition="'$(IsWebApplication)' == True And !Exists('$(MSBuildProjectFullPath).user')">
    <ItemGroup>
      <CSProjUserContent Include="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;" />
      <CSProjUserContent Include="&lt;Project ToolsVersion=&quot;15.0&quot; xmlns=&quot;http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003&quot;&gt;" />
      <CSProjUserContent Include="&lt;PropertyGroup&gt;" />
      <CSProjUserContent Include="&lt;LastActiveSolutionConfig&gt;Debug|Any CPU&lt;/LastActiveSolutionConfig&gt;" />
      <CSProjUserContent Include="&lt;/PropertyGroup&gt;" />
      <CSProjUserContent Include="&lt;/Project&gt;" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <WriteLinesToFile File="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath).user" Lines="@(CSProjUserContent)" ContinueOnError="true" />
  </Target>
```

`IsWebApplication` is computed like this:

```
<IsWebApplication>$(ProjectTypeGuids.Contains('349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21'))</IsWebApplication>
```

Finally, the target is part of a larger series of targets that run at the beginning and validate the csproj matches our requirements or ensure certain conditions:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EnsureXyzProjectSettingsDependsOn>
      AssertIISExpress;
      AssertNoAssemblyInfo;
      AssertDebugSymbols;
      AssertLocalApplicationHostFile;
      AssertImportsDFVersioning;
      EnsureSharedBinLink;
      AssertSharedBinOutputPath;
      AssertHintPaths;
      EnsureCSProjUserForWebApplications
    </EnsureXyzProjectSettingsDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="EnsureXyzProjectSettings" 
          DependsOnTargets="$(EnsureXyzProjectSettingsDependsOn)" 
          BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" 
          Condition="'$(SuppressStrictXyzTargetsChecks)' != true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, you can feel free to mark it as it's quite good work!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

- Set the build verbosity to Diagnostic.
- Build and look for where the msbuild file is located that generates this file:
  `TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs`
- Look for some conditions that you can alter to prevent the file from being
  generated.
- Set some property to alter the condition and prevent that file from being generated.

Comment: Already did. You cannot do it - they did not provide any hooks. The only solution is to execute the same logic artificially when building with MSBuild. This way this garbage is generated consistently and always. My question is not about it, but about the property `LastActiveSolutionConfig` being written to `.csproj.user` file for web application projects.My current workaround is to generate the damn file myself during msbuild console build as well.